# Python: Formatting wav data of variable length into specific length

Tags: python, wav, data-analysis

I'm trying to create a program that will read and analyze .wav files, find the magnitude + frequency in regards to time, set it into an array ([time magnitude frequency] (id est: [x y z])) and run it through a neutral network. My issue is that I need a constant number of values, but the audio clips have differing lengths.

How can I 'average' (in a sense) the data in order to create an array of, for example, 20 000 values out of say 22050, as well as doing the same to an array of 17500?

Also would it be best to do this (if possible) with the raw .wav data, or with the magnitude/frequency

Edit: For clarification, I'm looking to keep the audio unchanged, so not speeding it up/slowing it down as I'm using it for a voice recognition program for my voice specifically.

I'm also looking to avoid adding null values to the end of the array, but I might have to resort to this.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest pre-processing the audio files in this case. If you are using the python "wave" library. You can use this to read a file and then write it out with a modified rate.

Eg:

```
...
outfile = wave.open("processed.wav", "rb")
outfile.setframerate(original_rate/factor)
...
```

If factor is > 1 then you will shorten the file (fastplay) if it's < 1 you will "stretch" (slowplay). You can calculate the factor easily based on goal_length/actual_length.

Comment: Do you know if SciPy has a function like this? Also wouldn't it change the frequencies?

Comment: Sorry, that's beyond my previous experience. Frequencies ought to average based on your input data. I can't give much more info then just giving it a try in this case. Sorry.